# Pages not displaying as sections on static page

Tags: theme-development, menus, pages, static-website

I'm currently working on the Twenty-Nineteen theme. I'm trying to make each "page" display as a section on my homepage. This has worked in previous themes (i.e. Twenty Seventeen), however I'm clearly missing a step. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. I've already gone into my settings (both from the dashboard and within the customizer)

Comment: Hi Tim. It's hard to know what step you missed without knowing what steps you've taken. Can you describe what you've tried?

Comment: This is a feature of Twenty Seventeen only, and not part of Twenty Nineteen.

Comment: It certainly appears as though it is not a part of Twenty-Nineteen. I got this feature to work in Twenty-Seventeen because I used custom anchor links (w/Elementor) on the main page and thereby set up "sections" on my static page. Thanks Jacob!